# Spring Tools Suite 4 stops working autocomplete after a while

Tags: spring-tool-suite

When I'm using **STS (Spring Tools Suite) 4**, the autocomplete stops working for no apparent reason, and the only solution I find is to stop all my work, close the STS and reopen again. But this interruption is extremely annoying.

I couldn't find the cause of the problem. It happens randomly sometime after I start working. The autocomplete screen stuck like the image above showing that "1 pending" and it never finishes.

[image: AutoComplete freezes with this "1 pending"]

> Version: 4.8.1.RELEASE
> Build Id: 202010230733

Answer (score 0):

This sounds related to https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues/579, so please follow up on the GitHub issue with more details. Especially a thread dump of the IDE process as well as the language server process would be extremely helpful in debugging the fixing the issue.

As a workaround, you could go to the `Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content-Assist -> Advanced` and disable the `Language Server Proposals`. That will most likely help to avoid the problem (but also disables some of the Spring Boot related additional content-assist features for the moment) until we fixed the underlying issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I realized there was a newer version, so I updated (Version: 4.9.0.RELEASE, Build Id: 202012132054). Because the error seems to occur near randomly I'll test the workaround this week and send you the feedback (here or on GitHub).